# android gradle unable to add scandit library

Tags: android

I am working with scanditsdk. It works file with eclipse. I converted the project to android studio and now get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load scanditsdk-android-4.0.1 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.poshost.posapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/in.poshost.posapp-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.initializeRecognitionEngine(ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.java:985)
            at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.<init>(ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.java:195)
            at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker.<init>(ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker.java:65)
            at in.poshost.posapp.fragment.main.ScanditCameraFragment.onCreateView(ScanditCameraFragment.java:29)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at in.poshost.posapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have added the following line to the build.gradle file inside my PosApp module

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7_2')
    compile files('libs/scanditsdk-barcodepicker-android-4.0.1.jar', 'libs/armeabi.jar', 'libs/libscanditsdk-android-4.0.1.so.jar')
}
```

This is what the file structure looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your library folders in main/jniLibs. It worked for me.